# mysql query not working if middle text is missing

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to search user based on `full_name`.  I have database table with field `full_name`

Here are the records of table table : `users`

```
ID      full_name
1       adam bell nithan jhon albrt
2       ali imam khan
```

If i use query like this then it will work,

```
select * from users where full_name like '%ali imam%'
select * from users where full_name like '%adam bell%'
```

But if i search like this it will not work,

```
select * from users where full_name like '%adam bell nithan albrt%'
select * from users where full_name like '%ali khan%'
```

I dont know why this happening even we used proper like query. Is there any solution regarding this issue?

Comment: Full text index with full text search. `MATCH` and `AGAINST`

Comment: it wont work like that ,the `'test%'` wildcard means anything after the word test and `'%test'` means anything wich ends with test

Comment: Beacuse like query matches the text pattern you have entered.

Comment: @FerozAkbar so is there any solution?

Comment: Try something like `like '%adam bell nithan %albrt%'` I saw a similar question the other day, and someone suggested that syntax, or something like it. You can also use an `OR` with another LIKE in there too.

Comment: replace spaces with %

Comment: @Fred-ii- can you tell me how i use other like query?

Comment: @frz3993 `match` `against` will search in all the similar names for `adam bell nithan `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
select *
from users
where full_name like concat('%', replace('adam bell nithan albrt', ' ', '%'), '%');
```

It replaces the spaces with wildcards.  However, you are still stuck with the ordering of the names.

I think you should look into full text search functions (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html)).  I think it might be exactly what you need, and the performance is much better than `like`.

Comment: As I mentioned to the OP in comments, noticed a similar question the other day where someone suggested something similar to what I left in comments. Wouldn't `like '%adam bell nithan %albrt%'` work? The other answer which I don't remember where it is now, was accepted.

Comment: @Fred-ii- . . . No.  That will not match `'adam bell nithan jhon albrt'` becahse of `'jhon'`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I guess the other answer given might have been different, yet similar.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i tried this query but getting this error `Error in query (1064): Syntax error near '' at line 3`